# Linking directly to the Write Review page from iPhone

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have been trying to redirect the user to the review page.

I tried 3 different URL formats:

[{http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=350212768&mt=8}](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=350212768&mt=8)

(goes to the product page on safari)

{http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/british-accent/id350212768?mt=8#}

(Goes to the product page in iTunes store on the device)

{[http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=350212768&pageNumber=0& sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=350212768&pageNumber=0&%20sortOrdering=1&type=Purple%20Software&mt=8)}

(results in too many redirects)

Could you please tell me what the URL format should be to link
directly to the review page? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing worked on simulator, from the device {[http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=350212768&pageNumber=0&  sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=350212768&pageNumber=0&%20%20sortOrdering=1&type=Purple%20Software&mt=8)} works fine.

Comment: Any solution for ios7 anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Check out Appirater - http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/

Checks how many times a user has used your app, and will pop up an alert box asking them if they'd like to rate/review your app.

Comment: Is it redirecting user to Review tab in iOS 7 ?