# How to directly link to my app rating site in the App Store application?

Tags: iphone

I wonder how Tapbots managed to link directly to the rating site of Convertbot. When you tap the button, the App Store app launches and you immediately see the ratings of Convertbot plus a huge button titled "Rate this app" (or similar).

How to figure out this link, and how to launch the App Store app to go to that page?

Assuming having an app called FooBar with id 1234567890?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595906/linking-directly-to-the-write-review-page-from-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check out the [Appirater](http://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/) project that [Arash Payan](http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/) has put together.

Pretty much handles the checking and displaying of the "rate my app" prompt, and brings the user right into the review portion of your app on the App Store.

It's a very clean, and elegant way to provide that minimum barrier so that your users are more likely to submit reviews of your app.

Hope this helps...